# Android Studio not show build project or run button

Tags: java, android-studio

I am working on a project and moving it from my old AS to the latest AS Hedgehog but it turned out to be hard for me. After opening my project from file, AS just showed make module under Build section and the Run button went grey under Run section. Please help me with this. Thanx.